# Distance between two functions in term of a third function

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, geometric-functional-analysis

I am wondering if it is possible to define a distance between two real-valued functions that express the concept of "the space between them that can be filled by a third function", where the third function is fixed.

Consider functions defined on a domain $\mathcal{D}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, fix a function $s$ (in my mind something gaussian-shapedw with the peak inside $\mathcal{D}$). For simplicity $\int_\mathcal{D} s(x) dx=1$. See figure.

[image: sketch]

I would define the distance between $f$, $g:\mathcal{D}\to\mathbb{R}$ as:

$$
d(f, g) = \left|\mathrm{Argmin}_{N_s} \int_\mathcal{D}dx \left|f(x) + N_s s(x) - g(x) \right|\right| = \left|\mathrm{Argmin}_{N_s} d_{L1}(f+N_s s, g)\right|
$$

Is it possible to find a set of hypothesis that makes $d$ a proper distance? I am open also to small changes to the definition of $d$. I am interested when the functions are positive, or when they are as probability density functions, but not necessary normalized to 1.

For sure $d(f, g)\geq 0$, I think it is easy to prove $d(g, f)=d(f, g)$:

$$d(g, f) = \left|\mathrm{Argmin}_{N_s} d_{L1}(g+N_s s, f)\right|
=\left|\mathrm{Argmin}_{N_s} d_{L1}(f-N_s s, g)\right|=\left|-\mathrm{Argmin}_{N_s} d_{L1}(f+N_s s, g)\right| = d(f, g)$$

I am not sure about $d(f, g)=0\Rightarrow f=g$ and the triangular property.

A less local definition may be:

$$
d(f, g) = \left|\mathrm{Argmin}_{N_s} \max_{\mu\in C} \int_\mathcal{D}dx \left|f(x) + N_s s(x, \mu) - g(x) \right|\right|
$$

with $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathcal{D}$ where $\mu$ is something related to the location of $s$, for example the expected value of $s$.